# Handling logger directory when importing a class into another file in child folder

Tags: python

I have the following class directory:

```
project_directory/
....__init__.py
....class_file.py
....logger_folder/
....unittest_folder/
.........class_file_test.py
```

I have a class defined in class_file.py and I want to test it from class_file_test.py in the unittest_folder. The class_file.py contains a logger, defined as follows:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    filename='./logger_folder/class_file.log')
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

To test class_file from the unittest folder, I imported class_file using the following code in class_file_test.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from class_file import MyClass
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\project_folder\\unittest_folder\\logger_folder\\class_file.log'
```

So, clearly the unittest imported the class_file code and then used "." I use to define the filename for the logger relative to its own path. What is the right way to handle locating directories in such a file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your directory setting. Currently you are using relative path of current working directory. In practice, you should use absolute path or relavetive path of that file's directory.

```
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
print(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), "file.log"))
```